# Compiling Delphi to Java Class *.aar

Tags: java, android, delphi, rfid

Recently I'm developing program to scan RFID and Barcode on Java-Android for Zebra RFD8500 using RFIDAPI3 SDK. The SDK it self are on *.aar format and I'm use Android Studio as IDE. The problem are on RFIDIDAPI3 SDK, I want to add some function on their source code to ease of use.

There are some method on their library as shown bellow

```
public void setBeeperVolume(BEEPER_VOLUME beeperVolume) throws InvalidUsageException, OperationFailureException {
        if(null == beeperVolume) {
            throw new InvalidUsageException("setBeeperVolume - beeperVolume", "ERROR_PARAMETER_NULL");
        } else {
            SetAttribute var2 = new SetAttribute(140, "B", beeperVolume.getValue(), 0);
            RFIDResults var3 = l.a(this.c, var2);
            if(RFIDResults.RFID_API_SUCCESS != var3) {
                be.a(this.c, "setBeeperVolume", var3, true);
            }

        }
    }
```

As the snippet code shown above are from decompiled .class file, the method only execute command `140` and what I need are to execute command `1664`.

For information command 140 are intended for increasing volume beeper and 1664 are for change mode from RFID to Barcode or vice versa. Until now the RFIDAPI3 SDK are not supporting to change mode command so I want to add some new function on their SDK.

Their SDK are published on [github](https://github.com/FMXExpress/ZebraRFIDSDK) and unfortunately their source code on Delphi and I'm not familiar with that. The function on delphi are in this [link](https://github.com/FMXExpress/ZebraRFIDSDK/blob/a3a530da658ec9bcf71be4b5de4835ec96ff45b1/Android/com.zebra.rfid.api3.Config.pas#L59)

```
procedure setBeeperVolume(beeperVolume : JBEEPER_VOLUME) ; cdecl;           // (Lcom/zebra/rfid/api3/BEEPER_VOLUME;)V A: $1
```

I had added issue / update request on their github on this [link](https://github.com/FMXExpress/ZebraRFIDSDK) but no one respond.

I know reverse engineering are hard to do, not 100% success, and also not good practices.

So is there any way to me to develop a new function and build the aar class from the source code?

Or is there any tricky method (somehow like reverse engineering method) to change value from decompiled class?

Or any method to inherit some kind a tricky java method?

Please your guidance. Really appreciated it.
Thanks

Comment: That Github link is *not* the RFIDAPI3 SDK; it's a Delphi import of it. This is the SDK: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/rfid-sdk-for-android.html. If you want to enhance their functionality, perhaps you could ask them? If that's not the case, it's a little unclear as to what you're asking

Comment: @DaveNottage I had already asked them and their respond only "until now we cannot adding the functionality it self, good luck!" is there any method to edit class file? I had use ASM and BCEL and still wondering how to use both of them

Comment: And your link only download the library on aar files and demo application. I have tried before.

Comment: A possible solution in Java is to place a new, modified, class in the class path *before* the AAR (or JAR) so that the Android runtime uses this instead of the existing class. However the modified class must implement the same public/protected API. This is only the Java side, the Delphi import is a different beast.

Comment: I had do that but the constructor on the main class are not public so I cannot implement that class. And some code on the object on method are vague. I cannot only Override, copy, and change the number.